# How can I check the number of iterations per second without using time module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I would like to check how many iterations are completed per second or how many urllib requests are sent per second, but without slowing down the program at all (which time.sleep() seems to do). This is the program, for example:

```
while True:
    url = urllib.request.urlopen("google.com")
```

I would also like for the requests/per second counter to update in miliseconds, so it may print something like

"2.83 requests per second"
and then update to "2.93 requests per second" if the loop iterates faster.

Comment: I use `tqdm` from pip. It only updates every few iterations, so it's much more performant than some other solutions.

Comment: How are you using time.sleep()? I assume you are using it in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `time` and a counter to accomplish this.  I also added a custom generator (because I couldn't find one within Python's libraries) that allows you to both set and access the `i` value.

```
import time, itertools

def byRefCount():
    i = [0]
    while True:
        yield i[0],i
        i[0] += 1

last = time.time()
for i,ref in byRefCount():
    url = urllib.request.urlopen("google.com")

    if time() - last > 1:
        print(i / (time.time()-last))
        ref[0] = 0
        last = time.time()
```